# Transferring state between two components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a searchForm component that renders a searchResult component.  When the searchForm gets the results, it should **pass the state to the result's state**.
This where I fail.

```
var SearchForm = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            golden_record: {}
        }
    },
    handleSearchSubmit: function (search_param) {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url_variation,
            type: 'GET',
            data: search_param,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState(
                    {
                        ...
                    }
                );
            }.bind(this),
        });
        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url_golden,
            type: 'GET',
            data: search_param,
            success: function (data) {
                var golden_record = {
                    'site': data.sites[0].name,
                    'country': data.sites[0].country,
                };
                this.setState({'golden_record': golden_record});
            }.bind(this),
        })
    },
    render: function () {
        return (

                <div className="searchResult">
                    <SearchResult
                        golden_record={this.state.golden_record}
                    />
                </div>

        );
    }
});
```

**SearchResult:**

As you can see I am passing the `golden_record` as a property to the SearchResult. Inside SearchResult, when I set `value` of `<input />` to the property `this.props.golden_record['site']`, the input is fixed to that value. But I want to set value rather to `this.state.site` so that I can change it afterwards, if I wanted to. So I don't know how to copy the read-only value of the prop to the state.

```
 <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Facility name" name="facilityName" onChange={this.onSiteChanged} value={this.props.golden_record['site']} ref="facilityName"></input>
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `SearchResult` component, you could set your state in `componentWillReceiveProps`:

```
var SearchResult = React.createClass({
  ...
  getInitialState: function(){
     return {
        site: ''
     } 
  },
  componentDidMount: function(){
     this.setState({ site: this.props.golden_record.site });
  },
  componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps){
     this.setState({ site: newProps.golden_record.site });
  },
  render: function(){
     return  <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Facility name" name="facilityName" onChange={this.onSiteChanged} value={this.state.site} ref="facilityName"></input>
  }
});
```

Comment: That works. Many thanks. But it doesn't seem I needed the `componentDidMount ` in here.  The solution was `componentWillReceiveProps`.

Comment: Awesome, glad it works. I just put the  `componentDidMount` in there because `componentWillReceiveProps` is only called after the initial mount and I thought that your component might be initialized with data.